# Pyspark: How to pass the argument in the sql scripts while executing through hive context

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am sending the column name in the for loop and want use that variable(which contains column name) in the sql query inside for loop. Could you please help

```
for line in tcp.collect():
hive_context.sql("SELECT 'zip' as Variable_name,percentile(zip, 0.25) as Q1, percentile(zip, 0.75) as Q3 FROM df_tab").show()  -- Zip should be replaced by variable line

I tried to do something like this as well, but it dint work
query="SELECT {d_line} as Variable_name, percentile({line}, 0.25) as Q1, percentile({line}, 0.75) as Q3 FROM df_tab".format(d_line=line) --this gives me output as
```

SELECT zip as Variable_name,percentile(zip, 0.25) as Q1, percentile(zip, 0.75) as Q3 FROM df_tab --here zip has to come in single quote

Expected Output query: SELECT 'zip' as Variable_name,percentile(zip, 0.25) as Q1, percentile(zip, 0.75) as Q3 FROM df_tab

Answer (score 0):

```
query="SELECT {d_name} as Variable_name, percentile({f_name}, 0.25) as Q1, percentile({f_name}, 0.75) as Q3 FROM df_tab GROUP BY {f_name}".format(f_name=line, d_name="'"+str(line)+"'")
```